# Infrastructure Requirements for SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, hardware, hybrid-solution

What are the hardware requirements to implement a SP2013 Hybrid architecture farm with below :

Should be a  medium farm with

- 2 WFE
- 1 App
- SQL Cluster
- ADFS server
- AD
- Reverse Proxy.

Comment: We cannot answer this question without knowing amount of users, usage scenarios, use cases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware requirements for these servers should be different than when you do requirement and capacity planning for regular SharePoint farms. It will depend on number of users hitting your site, number of users in AD, amount of data, etc..

For this, here are some links that would be helpful to you as you would need to refer to them for your own needs and see what would be better for your case:

[ADFS Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678034.aspx)

[SharePoint Requirements](http://zoom.it/AgjL#full)

[Federation Server Proxy Capacity](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749898.aspx)